# Run MySQL command after 5 sec When I Run Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I Know It seems Weird But I Want To Run This MySQL Query

```
UPDATE section_data SET s_a = 1 WHERE s_a = 0;
```

but I don't want to run Immediately. When I Execute this query. i want to run this query with 5 sec delay when i Execute this code. is it possible?

Comment: I think you should re-think your application design.

Comment: Or delay calling the sql statement in your application.

Comment: What is your application programming language?

Comment: my programming language is php

Answer (score 0):

Would this do what you want?

```
UPDATE section_data SET s_a = 1 WHERE s_a = 0 AND SLEEP(5) = 0;
```

[`SLEEP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep) is a MySQL function that pauses for a given number of seconds, then returns `0`.

The downside is that it would probably lokc the row for 5 seconds. It is probably better yet to run two different queries:

```
SELECT SLEEP(5);
UPDATE section_data SET s_a = 1 WHERE s_a = 0;
```